# How to multiply selected range with selected number in Excel via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to simplify the macro I am using in Excel to multiply selected range. I often export data from SAP and the values are formated as text. An easy way to change them to numbers is to multiply them by 1. I also sometimes need to multiply values by -1 or any other number. 
I created a macro that does what I need, but as you can see, it has to find a blank cell, write the value in it, multiply selected range and delete the value. I would like to have a macro without the process of finding the blank cell and writing anything in it.

```
Sub macro()
    Dim Cinitel As Integer
    Dim PocetRadku As Long
    Dim PocetSloupcu As Integer

    Cinitel = InputBox("Enter a number to multiply with")

    PocetSloupcu = Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    PocetRadku = Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    Cells(PocetRadku + 1, PocetSloupcu) = Cinitel
    Cells(PocetRadku + 1, PocetSloupcu).Copy

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
      SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

    Cells(PocetRadku + 1, PocetSloupcu) = ""

    Calculate
End Sub
```

I can't use DataObject to put some value in Clipboard.

I came up with something like this but it does not work obviously :)

```
Sub macro1() 
    Dim myString As String 
    Dim number As Integer 

    number = InputBox("Enter a number to multiply with") 
    myString = Selection.Address 
    myString.Formula = Application.Evaluate("=" & myString & "*" & number)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Can't you just do `Selection.NumberFormat = "0"`, and if you need a multiplier then `Selection.Value = Selection.Value * (-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Sub test1()

    Dim rng As Range, nbr as integer

    Set rng = Selection
    nbr = InputBox("Enter a number to multiply with") 
    rng.Value = Evaluate("IF(" & rng.Address & "<>""""," & _
                rng.Address & "*" & nbr & ","""")")

    Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```